# Fastest language for computationally intensive functions in Oracle

Tags: oracle

Currently we have quite a few functions (normal CDF, inverse CDF, Vasicek and all kinds of derivatives) coded out in PL/SQL, but they are very slow.

I can get much better performance by streaming the data over a workstation where I have coded out things in C# and then bulk insert the results back. This approach however leaves the network as the bottleneck, it would be much better if I could 'put the mill where the wood is' by having faster functions inside the Oracle DB.

I want to see how I can speed that up by coding it out in either c(++) or Java (or any other alternative you may have). Does anyone here have any experience with this? Hopefully one of you has tried all approaches and can explain which has worked best overall.

Extra complication here is that IT is busy as it is, so if I want a waiver to use some feature on the DB I need to make a solid case. I don;t get to play around much on that box, else I would do that.

We're on Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Thanks in advance,

Gert-Jan

**EDIT**

Here's an example of what a function, which is the [Normal CDF by Cody](http://home.online.no/~pjacklam/notes/invnorm/#The_distribution_function).

The difference between this and the `cume_dist` is that `cume_dist` finds the distribution within a set of rows. I just need to convert a probability into standard deviations and back (a lot of times), like the `NORMDIST` and `NORMINV` functions in Excel.

```
    function stdnormal_cdf(u number) return number is
  z number;
  y Number;
  begin
    y:=abs(u);
    if y <= 0.6629126073623883041257915894732959743297 then
      z:=y * y;
      y:=u * ((((1.161110663653770e-002 * z + 3.951404679838207e-001) * z + 2.846603853776254e + 001) * z + 1.887426188426510e + 002) * z + 3.209377589138469e + 003)/((((1.767766952966369e-001 * z + 8.344316438579620) * z + 1.725514762600375e + 002) * z + 1.813893686502485e + 003) * z + .044716608901563e + 003);
      return 0.5  +  y ;
    else
      z:=exp(-y * y/2)/2;
      if y <= 5.65685424949238019520675489683879231428 then
        y:=y/1.41421356237309504880168872420969807857;
        y:=((((((((2.15311535474403846e-8 * y + 5.64188496988670089e-1) * y + 8.88314979438837594) * y + 6.61191906371416295e01) * y + 2.98635138197400131e02) * y + 8.81952221241769090e02) * y + 1.71204761263407058e03) * y + 2.05107837782607147e03) * y + 1.23033935479799725e03)/((((((((1.00000000000000000e00 * y + 1.57449261107098347e01) * y + 1.17693950891312499e02) * y + 5.37181101862009858e02) * y + 1.62138957456669019e03) * y + 3.29079923573345963e03) * y + 4.36261909014324716e03) * y + 3.43936767414372164e03) *  + 1.23033935480374942e03);
        y:=z * y;
      else
        z:=z * 1.41421356237309504880168872420969807857/y;
        y:=2/(y * y);
        y:=y * (((((1.63153871373020978e-2 * y + 3.05326634961232344e-1) * y + 3.60344899949804439e-1) * y + 1.25781726111229246e-1) * y + 1.60837851487422766e-2) * y + 6.58749161529837803e-4)/(((((y + 2.56852019228982242) * y + 1.87295284992346047) * y + 5.27905102951428412e-1) * y + 6.05183413124413191e-2) * y + 2.33520497626869185e-3);
        y:=z * (1/1.77245385102123321827450760252310431421-y);
      end if;

      if u < 0 then 
        return y;
      else 
        return 1-y;
      end if;    
    end if;  
  end;
```

**EDIT 2**

Ok so here are the benchmarks. Test table with 100k rows. The functions between Oracle and F# are pretty straight translations of each other and give the same result.

The query:

```
select 
    sum(get_rwa(approach, exposure_class_code, pd_r, lgd_r, ead_r, maturity_r, net_sale, rwf_r)) 
from functest
```

- Interpreted: 12.8 sec
- Native: 13.2 sec
- .Net (F#): 0.04 sec.

This would make the .Net function 320x (!) faster than the Oracle implementation, I really don't understand where this difference could come from. Anything up to 3-10x would seem reasonable. I really think I'm missing something here. Anyone?

In F# I loaded the 100k rows into a List first. (seemed fair, just summing up any other column in Oracle cost 0.06 seconds, so it seemed fair to exclude the data access time in both cases. It takes about 3 sec to load the data into a list, so even if I include the time it takes to open up the connection, execute and stream over the networks etc, then still it's 4x faster.)

Comment: Have you profiled the pl/sql?   If so what did it point at?

Comment: Actually no, didn't know that existed. Hope I have priviliges for that. I'll get back on this.

Comment: Google DBMS_PROFILER as a start

Comment: I'd be interested to see a stored proc (with easy access to the data) that performs slower than some C# program.  NOt saying it can't happen, but most likely the pl/sql code could be improved dramatically.  CAn you post a simple example of the type of pl/sql you tried?

Comment: I updated the question with an example. What I heard is 'marshalling the PL/SQL engine', or that the generated code is not optimized well etc, I'm no expert at all on the internals of Oracle. What I'm looking for is a function that will execute very fast.

Comment: Thanks for example, native compilation as Justin notes can help, but I doubt it will be dramatically faster.  Are you sure this function is the performance bottleneck?  How are you calling it? (i assume looping through some cursor of data).  If you say that C# pgm gives much better performance, I doubt its because of a .NET implementation of this one function.

Comment: Hi, I'm working on a benchmark to see what the difference is right now, by doing a select sum(functions(par1, par2, par3) from table. Actually there are many functions executed  through complicated joins etc so it;s hard to pinpoint where it comes from. In C# I have more contriol over this. I'll report the benchmark when it's done.

Comment: Ran the benchmark and updated question. Turns out you're right, native did not help at all. Still puzzled by the very large difference in perf between Oracle and .Net.. Guess I will have to take a look at external procedures..

Comment: Your benchmark is calling a function `get_rwa` but the only function you've posted is `stdnormal_cdf` which makes it a bit hard to reproduce.  Is `get_rwa` deterministic?  Is it declared as deterministic?  Could you create a function-based index on `get_rwa` to speed up the retrieval (clocking the expense of computing the result at `insert` time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gert-Jan,

Likely, the time difference is due to context switching between the SQL engine and the PL/SQL engine. Each of the 100,000 rows in functest is put through the PL/SQL routine get_rwa (and/or stdnormal_cdf). A context switch involves saving state and restoring state which you probably won't notice when done once. But doing it 100,000 times adds up.

So I'd suggest loading up the 100,000 rows in a nested table with 100,000 rows and pass this nested table only once to a PL/SQL-routine that does a simple "for i in 1 .. [nested_table_variable].count loop ... end loop;", while summing up the individual outcomes.

Another alternative is doing it all in SQL without resorting to PL/SQL.

Regards,
Rob.

Comment: Do you know if using any of the external procedures (c, java, .Net) would not incur this overhead? Will give doing the whole thing from PL/SQL a try.

Comment: It depends on how you use those procedures. Inside SQL (if possible, I don't know for sure) context switching will occur once for each row as well. When called from PL/SQL, after loading all rows in a collection upfront, you won't have this overhead.

Comment: Ok thanks for that.. so if I can chop up my work in smaller batches then I could run them from within the PL/SQL engine and be faster. Need to do some 30M rows and each of them with many different scenarios etc.. Was hoping for a lean as possible user experience but maybe I can wrap this in some kind of procedure. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Oracle supports the ability to [define and call external procedures](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg11rtn.htm).  Assuming you can compile your C/ C++/ C# application into a DLL/ .so and move that library to the database server, you could then expose the DLL's functions as external procedures and then call the DLL's functions from within the database.  Since everything would be running on the same machine, the network wouldn't be a bottleneck.  Of course, that would mean that your C/ C++/ C# code would be using the server's processing resources-- that may or may not be a good thing depending on how beefy the server's CPUs are compared to the workstation's and what else the server is doing.

Depending on exactly how you have coded the logic in PL/SQL, you might also want to look into either leveraging Oracle's built-in analytic functions like [cume_dist](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions035.htm) for cumulative distributions (I'm assuming that's what you mean by "normal CDF") or writing your own analytic functions.  Since your code is computationally intensive, it's also reasonably likely that you could benefit from [native compilation](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/plsql-new-features-and-enhancements-11gr1.php#native_compilation).  Of course, this assumes that you have profiled the code and that there aren't obvious places/ approaches to tuning the PL/SQL as it sits.

Comment: hi, I updated te question, cume_dist finds the cum dostribution of a set of rows, I need to convert probablities (0-100%) into standard deviations (roughly -5-+5) and back again a lot of times, like the NORMDIST and NORMINV functions in Excel. They don;t seem to exist in Oracle so we wrote our own. But that seems to be quite slow and I don;t know yet why.

Comment: Theexternal procedures is what I was thinking of, I was hoping someone would have had good results with one approach. There might be pitfalls or issues that might make one approach work better than the other, but I couldn;t find anything on the perf of these approaches.

Comment: Voted answer for native compilation. If all this stuff was indeed inetrpreted that would easiliy explain the poor perf. Wow, bnever expected it could be that simple. Haven;t tested it yet but this seems very likely to fix it.

Comment: Hmmm, so far for the native theory, the native functions are actually a litle bit slower than the interpreted ones. Not getting this at all.

Comment: Sorry, native compilation turned out not to speed things up after all. I updated the example with benchmarks.